# Getting select value from a complicated dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, automation, protractor

I'm not dealing with the easiest dropdown here, while I can click the dropdown I can't catch the value inside it. Even if I could select the first value, that would help...

I've tried the typical `element(by.id('procurer-name', 'Armina OÜ')).click();` but nothing..

Front end uses Angular, the outer HTML goes something like this:

```
<select ng-if="!readOnly" class="form-control ng-scope ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" id="procurer-name" name="procurer-name" ng-model="$parent.model" ng-options="item.procurerId as item.name for item in $parent.data | orderBy : [&quot;name&quot;]" ng-required="$parent.required" ng-disabled="$parent.ngDisabled" ng-change="onChangeFn()" required="required" style=""><option value="" ng-if="!hideDefaultOption" translate="" class="">-Vali-</option><!-- ngIf: !hideDefaultOption --><!-- end ngIf: !hideDefaultOption --><option label="example" value="number:109704">example2</option><option label="example" value="number:109913">example</option></select>
```

Comment: What language is this?  Also, where are you getting "procurer-name?"  I see no HTML for that or any options at all.  Please add more HTML code as code and not a screenshot to your original post.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the description with Outer HMTL. The ID "procurer-name" is visible by just inspecting the element.

Comment: You didn't answer my language question, though.  This doesn't look like java code.  I can tell you how to handle select webelements in java but I don't know if it applies since I don't recognize the syntax you're using.  You should add the programming language as a tag.

Comment: It's Friday night and I don't have anyone to ask from, but as I read from the spec it's a Java application built on Spring framework.

Comment: Ah, then element must be a user-defined method, but the by.id doesn't look to align with the java version of selenium, it only has one parameter.  It might be an extended class, though.  Hard to give advice on non-standard frameworks, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, it does click on the element, but doesn't select the value.. Is there any way to choose the first value? like row (1) ? Is there any advice I could give for the developer to make this easier?

Comment: In java, you don't click a select element itself.  You instead first define it as a webelement with a locator, then convert it to a Select, then you can access the elements directly by index, value, or text.

Comment: Please refrain from posting screenshots of code; instead, post the actual code snippet.

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: I removed the images. Yet none of the simple solutions don't seem to work. Is there any example you could give on how to define java elements as webelements?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that `Armina OÜ` might be causing encoding issues in the script.
Use css selector to find option tag `starts with Armina` as below:

```
css: #procurer-name option[label^="Armina"]
```

Protractor code:

```
element(by.id('#procurer-name')).click();
element(by.css('#procurer-name option[label^="Armina"]')).click();
```

Equivalent xpath would be

```
xpath: //select[@id='procurer-name']//option[starts-with(@label, "Armina")]
```

Protractor code:

```
element(by.id('#procurer-name')).click();
element(by.xpath('//select[@id='procurer-name']/option[starts-with(@label, "Armina")]')).click();
```

Comment: The first one gives me 'element not found', could you give the full xpath code?

Comment: You might have to click the select first to load the options. I have added the click code.